# Conditional redirect to HTTPS in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Our Spring Boot application currently redirects to HTTPS regardless of whether `server.ssl.enabled` is set to true or not using the following configuration:

```
   @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain getSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.requiresChannel(crmr -> crmr.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
            .authorizeRequests(eir -> eir.anyRequest().permitAll()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).build();
    }
}
```

However, we need it to use HTTP when SSL is disabled.

How can the `SecurityFilterChain` creation validate `server.ssl.enabled` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conditionally redirect to HTTPS or use HTTP based on the `server.ssl.enabled` setting in your Spring Boot application, need to modify your `SecurityFilterChain` configuration and create a custom `SecurityFilterChain` that checks the value of **server.ssl.enabled** and configures the channel security accordingly.

Here is the sample code :

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // Configure the security filter chain for the default behavior.
        return httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .anyRequest().permitAll() // Allow all requests
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain secureSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // Configure the security filter chain for secure (HTTPS) requests.
        return httpSecurity
            .requiresChannel(channelConfigurer ->
                channelConfigurer
                    .requestMatchers(request -> request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
                    .requiresSecure() // Require HTTPS
            )
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .anyRequest().permitAll() // Allow all secure requests
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Conditionally choose between the default or secure security filter chain
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("server.ssl.enabled", "false"))) {
            return secureSecurityFilterChain(http);
        } else {
            return defaultSecurityFilterChain(http);
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header check with the appropriate header if your application is behind a reverse proxy or load balancer that handles HTTPS termination. This header check is commonly used when such intermediaries are involved.

Using this configuration, your Spring Boot application will redirect to HTTPS only when `server.ssl.enabled` is set to true, and it will use HTTP when `server.ssl.enabled` is set to false.

Comment: Thank you, @ruwan-prasad! The logic above worked. I also moved common logic into a static method and switched to using `@ConditionalOnProperty` to validate the property.